# What is the the fastest way to create image from bytes stream?

Tags: java, android

I have an electronic device (kind of scanner), that send bytes to android device via wifi.
In the android i am taking the bytes and create integer array(each number represent pixel).
Then i create png file with the bitmap class.
The image look as it should be.
I am processing the image in separate thread.
My goal is to create new image and replace the old image in the fastest way.
In fact i want to create illusion of movie.

The problem is that it took too much time to create images.

Here is the relevant code

```
Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(mBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
```

...

```
int count = mBufferIn.read(buffer);
while(count != -1)
{
for(int i=0;i<count;i=i+2)
{
    k = ((buffer[i] << 8) & 0x0000ff00) | (buffer[i+1] & 0x000000ff);
    Log.e("TCP Client", "k=" + Integer.toString(k) );   
    colors[pixelIndex]=k;
    pixelIndex++;
}
count = mBufferIn.read(buffer);

if(count ==-1)
{
         try {
                 pixelIndex=0;
             c.drawBitmap(colors, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height, false, paint);
```

...

I have change the code to this:

```
try {
                    while((numberOfRead =mBufferIn.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        babff.append(buffer, 0, numberOfRead);
                        //offset = offset + numberOfRead;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte [] imageBytes = babff.toByteArray();

                BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                opt.outHeight = height;
                opt.outWidth = width;

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length,opt);

                Paint paint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint1);
```

Now the problem is that the bitmap is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Generating image setting pixel by pixel is very slow. Read everything inside a byte array and create the bitmap from the byte array